# How to display JSON Object Data info?

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web

I have this PHP:

```
<?php
$page_id = 'FACEBOOKPAGEHERE';
$access_token = 'SECRETACCESTOKENHERE';
//Get the JSON
 $json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?access_token=' . $access_token);
//Interpret data
 $fbdata = json_decode($json_object);

 foreach ($fbdata->data as $post )
 {

 $posts .= '<p>' . $post->message . '</p>';
 $posts .= '<p>' . $post->created_time . '</p>';
 $posts .= '<p>' . $post->likes . '</p>';
 $posts .= '<br />';


}

 ?>
```

This code is to retrieve some info of my facebook page, so I can put it in the news box of my webpage.

Facebook give me a JSON file, which is the one I called in the `$json_object` but when I save this code inside my page test.php, I only see what it is in the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6WLL.png

I dont know what to do, I barely know PHP and this is new thing for me.
my objective is bring that info to me, pass it through CSS and make it beautiful.
This is the page that I'm making: http://watervfire.tk

Comment: Try using a different name for the variable $post call it $info_post also. do a print_r($post) to see what info comes from the data. and another Question do you have PHP installed? Because if you see code is because php is not interpreting the code as it should...

Comment: i have downloaded the last stable version, but it is just a large bunch of files, what should i do? tomorrow i will try changing the var names, cause here is laate night.. so goodnight! and thankyou :)